Not being able to change the width of a stroke
Today when I opened inkscape I found that when I make a stroke, the width does not change even if I go to properties and change the value

And when I try to open shape files I made, they look totally different. For example, I made this figure in inkscape

but now it looks like this when I open the file

Could someone guide me on what I can do? I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it's still the same.

You have Outline View on.  Switch it back to Normal.  Click on View > Display Mode > Normal.
